# How to move elements in an xml file within the tree

Tags: xml, awk, sed, xmlstarlet

I have an xml file of the following form:

```
<results>
 <sequence-name>name1</sequence-name>
 <repetitions>
  <window>
   <key1>1</key1>
  </window>
 </repetitions>
 <sequence-name>name2</sequence-name>
 <repetitions>
  <window>
   <key1>4</key1>
  </window>
  </repetitions>
</results>
```

I would like to move the element `sequence-name` such that it is the first element inside `window`, so the output should look like:

```
<results>    
 <repetitions>
  <window>
   <sequence-name>name1</sequence-name>
   <key1>1</key1>
  </window>
 </repetitions>    
 <repetitions>
  <window>
   <sequence-name>name2</sequence-name>
   <key1>4</key1>
  </window>
 </repetitions>
</results>
```

I tried using grep to produce two files, one containing just the lines with `<sequence-name>`, and one with all the other lines. But I can't figure out how to insert the lines containing `<sequence-name>` back into the place I would like. I'm guessing there is a solution using `sed/aw`k. I am also happy to use a tool such as `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: Not so easy. `xmlstarlet`'s `ed -m` command can move a single node, but not multiple nodes at a time. It looks like you will have to write some `xslt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following stylesheet should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/ | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::sequence-name)]" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="window">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="preceding::sequence-name[1]" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key1"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can apply it using `xsltproc stylesheet data` or `xmlstarlet tr stylesheet data`.

Answer (score 1):

If your files are always that well formed and it's non-trivial in xmlstarlet:

```
$ awk '/<sequence-name>/{s=$0;next} {print} /<window>/{print s}' file
<results>
 <repetitions>
  <window>
 <sequence-name>name1</sequence-name>
   <key1>1</key1>
  </window>
 </repetitions>
 <repetitions>
  <window>
 <sequence-name>name2</sequence-name>
   <key1>4</key1>
  </window>
  </repetitions>
</results>
```

and if you care about the indentation:

```
$ awk '/<sequence-name>/{s=$0; next} {print} /<window>/{indent=$0; sub(/[^[:space:]].*/," ",indent); sub(/^[[:space:]]*/,indent,s); print s}' file
<results>
 <repetitions>
  <window>
   <sequence-name>name1</sequence-name>
   <key1>1</key1>
  </window>
 </repetitions>
 <repetitions>
  <window>
   <sequence-name>name2</sequence-name>
   <key1>4</key1>
  </window>
  </repetitions>
</results>
```

Comment: Darn, I knew there'd be a one-line awk solution! Thanks, also works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another method, just using sed:

```
$ sed '/<sequence-name>/{s/^/  /; h; d;}; /<window>/G;' file
<results>
 <repetitions>
  <window>
   <sequence-name>name1</sequence-name>
   <key1>1</key1>
  </window>
 </repetitions>
 <repetitions>
  <window>
   <sequence-name>name2</sequence-name>
   <key1>4</key1>
  </window>
  </repetitions>
</results>
```